# In rad grid page style, how we can reduce the combo box size?

Tags: asp.net, combobox, radgrid, radcombobox

I am using the radgrid method from Sitefinity. I am using a pager style also. the code for mentioning the page style is

```
<rad:RadGrid ID="grdMeetings" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                            AllowPaging="True" SortingSettings-SortedDescToolTip="Sorted Descending" SortingSettings-SortedAscToolTip="Sorted Ascending"
                            PageSize="5" PagerStyle-PageSizeLabelText="Records Per Page" CellSpacing="-1" BorderStyle="None" Width="750px" AllowSorting="True">
    <PagerStyle PageSizeLabelText="Records Per Page"/>
                        </rad:RadGrid>
```

But I can't edit the combobox  width, I can see it's input type is text. How can I remove that input type?

Comment: What is "the radgrid method from Sitefinity"?

Comment: Do you mean the combobox of the `PagerStyle` template provided for the number of pages?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it. Set the desired width for the `GridPagerItem` in the `RadGrid_ItemCreated` event. In this case, the width is set to `50px`, modify it to your needs.

```
protected void RadGrid1_ItemCreated(object sender, GridItemEventArgs e)
{
  if (e.Item is GridPagerItem)
  {
      // ---------------------------------------------------------
      // This is how to adjust width of the RadGrid Pager ComboBox
      // ---------------------------------------------------------
      GridPagerItem oGridPagerItem = (GridPagerItem)e.Item;
      RadComboBox oRadComboBox = (RadComboBox)oGridPagerItem.FindControl("PageSizeComboBox");
      oRadComboBox.Width = Unit.Pixel(50);
   }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks for your replay. how can we apply this radgrid to given page style?

Comment: Just add the `ItemCreated` event for the rad grid definition like `OnItemCreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated"`